# Deleting a Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've used the Azure Portal to allocate my first Service Fabric cluster. Cool, but now I'm done playing with it for a few days and would like to de-allocate it so I'm not paying for it. But the Azure Portal appears to expose no obvious way to delete the cluster.

Surely I must be missing something. Can anyone tell me how to either "turn it off" so I'm not paying for it or delete it entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SF cluster resource is made of other Azure resources that you pay for. So in order for you to not get charged, you will have to either delete those resources one by one, including the Cluster resource or just delete the resource group, which will remove all the resources under it.

If you have other things in the RG and you want to keep them, you will have to delete the resources which support the SF cluster, they all are tagged two tags
1) clusterName:your cluster name
2) resourceType:Service Fabric

you can use those to narrow down the resources that you will have to delete.

Comment: I believe I have deleted everything except the Service Fabric Cluster itself. That is all I see left in the resourcegroup besides the other unrelated things I created myself. What is the appropriate powershell cmd to delete the cluster?

Comment: Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceName SF cluster name -ResourceGroupName RG name -ResourceType Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your resource group and the cluster will be deleted with it. Obviously, this only works if you have nothing useful in the same resource group.

Comment: Yeah I do have other things in that resource group. Is there really no other way to remove it? I just deleted the VMs associated with the cluster, but the cluster itself still exists. I know it's preview, but this is silly.

Comment: I am not aware of other ways

Comment: The only way is to delete the complete group. That is the recommended way as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Remove-AzureRmResource functions just fine on the SF resource. There is as of yet no button for this on the portal.