# Turning off ServiceFabric clusters overnight

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

We are working on an application that processes excel files and spits off output. Availability is not a big requirement.

Can we turn the VM sets off during night and turn them on again in the morning? Will this kind of setup work with service fabric? If so, is there a way to schedule it?

Comment: did you see this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365409/deleting-a-service-fabric-cluster

Comment: Thanks for the resource. But this doesnt explain if I can pause/Stop-Restart the cluster to save money.

Comment: You cannot. You can only decommission the whole set, because the cost is only based on the underlying resources, like VMs and load balancers. So deleting is in fact your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you all for replying. I've got a chance to talk to a Microsoft Azure rep and documented the conversation in here for community sake.

**Response for initial question**

A Service Fabric cluster must maintain a minimum number of Primary node types in order for the system services to maintain a quorum and ensure health of the cluster.  You can see more about the reliability level and instance count at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-capacity/.  As such, stopping all of the VMs will cause the Service Fabric cluster to go into quorum loss.  Frequently it is possible to bring the nodes back up and Service Fabric will automatically recover from this quorum loss, however this is not guaranteed and the cluster may never be able to recover.

However, if you do not need to save state in your cluster then it may be easier to just delete and recreate the entire cluster (the entire Azure resource group) every day.  Creating a new cluster from scratch by deploying a new resource group generally takes less than a half hour, and this can be automated by using Powershell to deploy an ARM template.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm/ shows how to setup the ARM template and deploy using Powershell.  You can additionally use a fixed domain name or static IP address so that clients don’t have to be reconfigured to connect to the cluster.  If you have need to maintain other resources such as the storage account then you could also configure the ARM template to only delete the VM Scale Set and the SF Cluster resource while keeping the network, load balancer, storage accounts, etc.

**Q)Is there a better way to stop/start the VMs rather than directly from the scale set?**

If you want to stop the VMs in order to save cost, then starting/stopping the VMs directly from the scale set is the only option.

**Q) Can we do a primary set with cheapest VMs we can find and add a secondary set with powerful VMs that we can turn on and off?**

Yes, it is definitely possible to create two node types – a Primary that is small/cheap, and a ‘Worker’ that is a larger size – and set placement constraints on your application to only deploy to those larger size VMs.  However, if your Service Fabric service is storing state then you will still run into a similar problem that once you lose quorum (below 3 replicas/nodes) of your worker VM then there is no guarantee that your SF service itself will come back with all of the state maintained.  In this case your cluster itself would still be fine since the Primary nodes are running, but your service’s state may be in an unknown replication state.

**I think you have a few options:**

1. Instead of storing state within Service Fabric’s reliable collections, instead store your state externally into something like Azure Storage or SQL Azure.  You can optionally use something like Redis cache or Service Fabric’s reliable collections in order to maintain a faster read-cache, just make sure all writes are persisted to an external store.  This way you can freely delete and recreate your cluster at any time you want.
2. Use the Service Fabric backup/restore in order to maintain your state, and delete the entire resource group or cluster overnight and then recreate it and restore state in the morning.  The backup/restore duration will depend entirely on how much data you are storing and where you export the backup.
3. Utilize something such as Azure Batch.  Service Fabric is not really designed to be a temporary high capacity compute platform that can be started and stopped regularly, so if this is your goal you may want to look at an HPC platform such as Azure Batch which offers native capabilities to quickly burst up compute capacity.

Answer (score 3):

No. You would have to delete the cluster and recreate the cluster and deploy the application in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off the cluster is, as Todd said, not an option. However you can scale down the number of VM's in the cluster.

During the day you would run the number of VM's required. At night you can scale down to the minimum of 5. Check this page on how to scale VM sets: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down/

Comment: Actually, the Minimum can be 3 nodes, if the durability plan "Bronze" is selected.

Comment: Using 3 nodes is considered a test cluster. From 5(or maybey even 4) nodes its considered being a production cluster. The portal.azure gives you this warning when selecting 3 nodes.

Comment: Absolutely. But still, the OP asked for options to minimise cost. This is one which does not require you to delete the cluster and obviously, the stability is not needed during that period during the night.

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes, you can create a [Dev/Test Lab Service Fabric cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/create-environment-service-fabric-cluster) which you can start and stop at will.

I have also been able to start and stop SF clusters on Azure by starting and stopping the VM scale sets associated with these clusters. But upon restart all your applications (and with them their state) are gone and must be redeployed.